# Clearing Javascript basics regarding variables

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(x);
x = 20;
```

the value returned on the console is undefined.
I was expecting a value of 20 or a reference error.
Why is that so??

Comment: How about `x=20; console.log(x); `

Comment: in strict mode, you would get the error use before declaration. otherwise it gets with use declared and has the value of ... `undefined`.

Comment: I know this will give me the required result.But I am asking why does'nt it work the other way even if the concept of variable hoisting is used.

Comment: @pirho What does that have to do with the question? He *wanted* to get an error by using the variable before assigning it.

Comment: I get a reference error when I type that into the console.

Comment: @Barmar I meant the same as the answers suggest. _on the console is undefined_, _I was expecting a value of 20_. Maybe I did not fully understand the question.

Comment: Click on "Run code snippet" and you'll get the expected error. You must be doing something different in your actual code.

Comment: @pirho he said he was expecting either 20 or an error. He didn't get either, he just got undefined with no error.

Comment: @pirho He's not asking how to get 20, he's asking why he didn't get one of those expected results.

Comment: Maybe your real code has `var x; console.log(x); x = 20;`

Comment: @Barmar You are right on that. But still: was expecting _20_.

Comment: @pirho I think what he means is that if he doesn't get an error, he thought it would be because the assignment somehow happens first.

Comment: @Barmar  my real code is the one I have specified..

Comment: @Barmar Yes I agree. But it seems it confused many answerers also.

Comment: @Erick The code you specified gets a reference error.

Comment: @Barmar

the code is ....
console.log(x);
var x=20;
it gives undefined as the answer

Comment: @Erick : snippet gives error `"message": "ReferenceError: x is not defined",`

Comment: @Erick I know that. And when I run that code I get a reference error.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome
@Barmar

Comment: That's what I'm using and I get the expected error. You don't get an error when you click on "Run code snippet"?

Comment: @Barmar that's because you clicked enter key after typing the first line .
Click shift+enter and add the second line and then press Enter

Comment: I still get the error when I do that. But why do you care what happens in the console, what matters is when you run real scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code returns error - `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined` not `undefined`.

So think of `x = 20;` as `var x = 20;` which prints `undefined` in console.

In `JavaScript` if you do not declare a variable before using it then the declaration happens first with default value `undefined`. Then happens the initialization for that variable.

Consider this code with `var`:

```
console.log(x);
var x = 20;
```

Actually interpreted by `JavaScript` Engine as:

```
var x;
x = undefined;
console.log(x);
x = 20;
```

Comment: That's only true if you have a variable declaration. An assignment is not a declaration.

Comment: but I have declared my variable after it has been displayed on the console. Should'nt it give a Reference Error??

Comment: @Erick You haven't declared your variable at all. A variable declaration begins with `var` or `let`.

Comment: i m using var @barmar

Comment: @Erick Not in the code you posted in the question.

Comment: @Erick, Check my updated answer.

Comment: @Mamun If that's the case why does it give an error if I write only console.log(x) and without the variable declaration.Then JavaScript engine interprets it as you mentioned it must give undefined value and not reference error..

Comment: @Erick, your code returns error not `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

It works as

Is there and variable/functions used take it at the top and  variable assigned as `undefined`

so `x= undefined;` at the top, and you got result as `undefined` in second line and then you changed `x=20` at last.

```
console.log(x);
x=20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when your doing `console.log(x);`, it referring to global scope (`window.x`) and the value of `x` in global scope (`window.x`) is `undefined`. When you do `x=20`, you are setting the value of `x` after it is already displayed.

Comment: If you refer to a variable that has never been declared you normally get an error "ReferenceError: x is not defined". Why doesn't that happen here?

Comment: But I guess it should return a Reference error as the value of x has not been declared.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a old trick, first print a variable, then set its value. 
To solve this you should first set the x, then console.log like this:

```
x=20;
console.log(x);
```

and what is happening with your question is:

1. Initially:
   The value of x is undefined
2. Log:

   Console.log(x); //this will print a empty line, because x is here undefined yet
3. Set variable x to 20:

   x=20; //the x is set, but without use.